# EditorFor an int chooses a string template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i have two EditorTemplates

```
string.cshtml
int.cshtml
```

when i write `EditorFor` a `string` or an `int` they both choose `string.cshtml`

and when i even remove `string.cshtml` , the `EditorFor` for an `int` dont choose `int.cshtml`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

EditorTemplates use CLR typenames, not C# keywords.
You need to create `Int32.cshtml`.

Comment: @NadeemKhedr: Because the system will fallback to `String.cshtml` if it can't find anything better.

Answer (score 6):

Your int template's name should be `Int32.cshtml`

The `string.cshtml` works because there is a CLR Type in System Namespace called `String` ;)

**Your templates names must be called like the type you want.**

#### More Information

- [ASP.NET MVC 2 Templates](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html)
- [Custom MVC Numeric EditorTemplate](http://thirstycrow.net/blog/2011/06/custom-mvc-numeric-editortemplate/)

Comment: The keyword `string` has the CLR type `System.String`, so that explains why the string template works and the int one does not.

Comment: @Dismissile yes i know. I updated my answer to provide more information.